# Could not find or load main class hello

Tags: java, windows, command-line

please, I really need some help with this! I'm working on my very first Java program - the classic "hello world" program. I saved the correct script on Notepad as Hello.java in C:\myProjects and used the command line to compile a Hello.class in the same folder. Even though the class *is* in the current directory, java *still* could not find it!

[Here is a screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q015s.jpg)

Then I tried to manually set a classpath, even though I *shouldn't* need to do that, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkzvu.jpg), but still the command line is not able to run the Hello.java program.

How do I fix this?? I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling my Java JDK altogether.

Comment: The error message here is 'could not find or load main class ...'. *Not* 'environment variable classpath not defined'. It doesn't have to be defined, and that message did not come from Java. Be accurate. And don't post pictures of text, or links to them. Post the text, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capitalize `Hello`
Your command needs to be `java Hello`

Java is case sensitive.

Comment: You're welcome, and I agree with @WrRaThY, you might want to get an IDE if you are going past _hello world_ programs.

Answer (score 0):

or you might just install IntelliJ IDEA / Eclipse / NetBeans and enjoy life a little bit more :D

example step-by-step video (and there are tons more of those):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypLISBPwIWc

Comment: Thank you WrRaThY!!